# Alternative to Geogebra

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, math-software

In Norwegian schools, [Geogebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoGebra) is widely used for plotting graphcs, calculus, algebra, etc. However, by the looks of it, it is not very commonly used, so the documentation and resources is very limited (especially on the Computer Algebra System). Is there any good alternatives to it? What is most used in other countries/professionally? This is only basic functions, like finding derivatives/extrapolating and solving polynomial equations, no 3D.

Comment: See also [these alternatives](https://readysetgeo.wordpress.com/challenges/alternatives-to-geogebra/).

Comment: For a computer algebra system, definitely go with Mathematica: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/ , it is very widely used and supported, a free and open source alternative that is very nice as well, is sage: http://www.sagemath.org/ . For, quick, on the go plotting, you probably already know about wolfram alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/ (both web and mobile app exists). For playing around with geometry like in GeoGebra I would say stay with GeoGebra actually, but otherwise: "The Geometer's Sketchpad": http://www.dynamicgeometry.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

Try Mathematica: https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/. It might be a little overpowered for what you're using it for, but I can almost guarantee it'll be sufficient.

Comment: You should perhaps mention that this piece of software is not free. It quite expensive in general, but if you can show that you are a student it's quite a reasonable price (at least for people in the first world).

Comment: Yes, I probably should have mentioned that. I honestly had forgotten, as my university pays for a copy that can be streamed from a central VM.